# G acts on L. H is a minimal normal subgroup. H abelian, and acts transitively. Prove G acts primitively on L.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$G$ acts on $L$. $H$ is a minimal normal subgroup (As in, H contains no normal subgroups). $H$  is abelian, and acts transitively. Prove $G$ acts primitively on $L$.

I'm hoping to get some advice on how to approach this problem. Since $H$ is abelian and acts transitively, we have $stab_H(l_1) = stab_H(l_2)$ for every $l_1,l_2 \in L$. We also have $G = Hstab_G(l_1)$ for any $l_1$, but I am not sure how to use the condition that $H$ is minimal normal subgroup. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As Boris Novikov wrote, $G$ acting primitively is equivalent to ${\rm stab}_G(l)$ being a maximal subgroup of $G$. If not, then there is a subgroup $J$ of $G$ with ${\rm stab}_G(l) < J < G$. Let $K = J \cap H$. Then $K$ is normal in both $J$ and by $H$ (because $H$ is abelian), so $K \lhd HJ=G$, and $1 < K < H$, contradicting the fact that $H$ is a minimal normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: OK, you are right.

Comment: @Derek Holt It can be argued that $K<H$, however what guarantee is there that $K \neq \{1_G\}$?

Answer (score 0):

There is some ambiguity in the question. I think that $H$ is a normal subgroup and a minimal subgroup. Then $H\cap stab_G(l)=1$ implies  $stab_G(l)$ is a maximal subgroup. The last is  occur iff $G$ is primitive [M.Hall, *The Theory of Groups*, 1959, Theorem 5.6.1]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you explain why we have $H \cap stab_G(l) = 1$?

Comment: I don't think there is any ambiguity (except that (s)he should have said that $H$ is a minimal normal subgroup of $G$). The phrase "$H$ is a minimal normal subgroup of $G$" of a group is standard. It means that $1 \ne H \unlhd G$ and there exists no normal subgroup $K$ of $G$ with $1 < K < H$.

Comment: Yes, Derek Holt is right.